# How to transform a sentence into an Algolia/Elasticsearch query?

Tags: elasticsearch, search, search-engine, algolia

I have a full-stack app using NextJS & Supabase. In my database I store locations with titles, descriptions and categories. These locations represent different types of places like restaurants, bars, parks... I would like to create an in-app search engine for the users to find the places from a sentence like "What are good bars in San Francisco ?" (a score could be added to  the table to rank the searches). I'm currently indexing the data on Algolia. Is the goal achievable with Algolia ? If not, what can I use to do that ?